# Performance Calling C from C#

Tags: c#, .net, c, raspberry-pi

Edit: To narrow the scope of this question a bit:

When the .NET framework invokes an external method, do I still incur the cost of all the .NET overhead **during the execution** of that method?

I am dipping my toes into the world of 'physical' computing. I have a Raspberry Pi, and I've been able to do a number of very cool things with it, such as execute C# code via mono, create custom network connection to my windows machine, access GPIO pins via python/C#.

However, now I am up against something I have never had to contend with in the .NET world of productivity applications: the speed of sound and electricity.

I have an ultrasonic range sensor. I am able to get a reading using Python, but the variance is too great for my liking. I also tried it from a C# wrapper, but that is even worse, to the point that my code cannot execute fast enough to even see the echo pin turn on and off.

So here is my question: if I write a small C function that will perform all the necessary state changes and readings on the board, will I reap the speed benefits while calling from C#? That is to say, when execution of an extern method begins from within in .NET framework... what is happening?

Comment: I don't know anything about c# but I am almost certain that it would work with python, so I don't see a reason why it wouldn't with c#.

Comment: Instead of polling for a pin to go high or low - which is bound to go wrong... - you should use an interrupt instead.

Comment: This may help: http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio

Comment: @JakobOlsen Can you point me towards a library or technique that supports interrupts? In my research I haven't been able to find such support.

Comment: You beat me to it! ;)

Comment: There is nothing that .NET can do to make C code slow.  There is overhead in calling it but Pinvoke is very highly optimized, basic cost is but a handful of nanoseconds.  But you can certainly fumble it by making the cost of copying the data too high.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. Can you elaborate briefly on 'copying the data?' Is that referring to parameters and return results? Pushing on the bounds of my knowledge, here.

Comment: No, this needs to start by you documenting your question properly.  You can at a minimum post your pinvoke declaration.

Comment: I have not yet written anything which calls an external function. I wanted to make sure I was going to be able to achieve my goal with this approach, first. Not sure how I could better document, I did give it much thought beforehand. Perhaps not the best fit for SO, as is the case with many questions. Anyway - thanks for the direction, my question is largely answered, and I know where to focus my research.

Comment: I'm not a Python user but Jakob is right you should be using interrupts. Does the following help, it sounds pretty straightforward to use them from Python: http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio